# Align Three DIV without collapsing the content inside the DIV

Tags: html, css

How to align three DIV side by side but prevent content inside it from collapsing. 
In the screenshot, as soon as I try to increase the font size of 2nd red box, 
whole DIV collpase and goes down on bottom.

```css
.admin_screen {
    display: inline-block;
}
h3.adscreen_header {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: beige;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
p.admintext {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* line-height: 31px; */
}
span.adminboldtext {
    font-weight: 600;
}
h3.screen1_header {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: beige;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.screen1header{
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="admin_screen">
          <h3 clasS="adscreen_header">患者用画面
</h3>
<p class="admintext"><span class="adminboldtext">デモ用URL</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.jyunbanmachi.com/asp/mid1212"><u>http://www.jyunbanmachi.com/asp/mid1212</u></a><br><span class="adminboldtext">ログインID</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;不要&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; パスワード&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 不要</p>
          <img src="images/admin_screen.png">
        </div>
        <div class="screen1header">
          <h3 clasS="screen1_header">待合室用&nbsp;　順番画面</h3>
          <p class="screen1text">デモの閲覧申し込みをして頂くとデモ用URLやログインID等をメールにてご案内いたします。</p>
           <img src=images/screen1.png></div>
```

Here I am trying to display 3 Picture, with its own title, subtitle then image.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN78E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write max-width property

```css
.admin_screen {
  max-width: 40%;
  float left;
}

.screen1header {
  max-width: 60%;
  float left;
}
```

or use flex box

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="admin_screen"></div>
  <div class="screen1header"></div>
</div>


.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.admin_screen {
    flex: 1; // change value
}
.screen1header {
    flex: 2; // change value
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I go for 33.33% rule for Three DIV ? + I see that all the DIV header title is combined, and only way to seperate is to play with `max-width:%` . so it will change the 33.33% . what will you recommend here?

Comment: Must be divided by column.
The column should have a max-width and padding value and put your content in it.
https://codepen.io/chris_cook/pen/qNxAXy  check this out.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I found similar quesitons in stack but it never mentioned about max width, thats why my content collapsed on increasing font size and all. This helped.